# Highchart loading in angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using highchart(donut chart) but it is loading before The api response in coming,which is resulting in that data is not rendering in it

I want to get value of this.Total_connect in the highchart

Want to get value in highchart disconnected field

PIE CHART IS LOADING IN STARTING INSIPITE OF LOADING AFTER API IS CALLED AND DATA HAS STORED IN VARIABLE

```
     ngOnInit(){
         this.getCustomerInfo1();
         this.getTotalDevice();
         Highcharts.chart('container', this.options);
          this.configuration = DefaultConfig;
          this.configuration.orderEnabled = false; 
             console.log("onInit data",this.data1);
             }


   //CODE FOR CALLING API
     getTotalDevice(){
    this.users2=this._dataService.getCustomerInfo().subscribe((result2) =>{
    this.users2=result2
     console.log("result array" + JSON.stringify(this.users2));
     console.log("connected total" +this.Connect_Total);
     this.ConnectMethod(this.Connect_Total);


      },
    (error)=>{

      })
      }



        //CODE FOR HIGHCHARTS
    public options: any = {
      chart: {
        type: 'pie',
       options3d: {
        enabled: true,
        alpha: 45
       }
    },
   title: {
      text: 'Connected vs disconnected'
   },
   subtitle: {
    text: '3D donut in Highcharts'
    },
    plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        innerSize: 100,
        depth: 45
       }
     },
     series: [{
    name: 'Delivered amount',
    data: [
        ['Connected', this.Connect_Total],
        ['DISCONNECTED', 3000],

        ]
     }]
    }
    }
```

Comment: Could you reproduce it in an online code editor like codesandbox? Check this example with `highcharts-angular` official Highcharts wrapper (can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) with asynchronous data update: https://codesandbox.io/s/l9v3vk58o7

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this is to pass around a reference to the observable, and then subscribe where you need the value of the response. That way, you're highcharts code will only run once the API response comes through. If you need to do anything else with the data, you can use a tap operator. Something like

```
ngOnInit(){
     this.getCustomerInfo1();
     let observable = this.getTotalDevice();
     observable.subscribe(customerInfoResult => {
       Highcharts.chart('container', this.options);
     })
     this.configuration = DefaultConfig;
     this.configuration.orderEnabled = false; 
     console.log("onInit data",this.data1);
   }


//CODE FOR CALLING API
 getTotalDevice(){
   return this._dataService.getCustomerInfo().pipe(tap((result2) =>{
     this.users2=result2
     console.log("result array" + JSON.stringify(this.users2));
     console.log("connected total" +this.Connect_Total);
     this.ConnectMethod(this.Connect_Total);
  },
  (error)=>{

  }));
}



    //CODE FOR HIGHCHARTS
public options: any = {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
   options3d: {
    enabled: true,
    alpha: 45
   }
},
title: {
  text: 'Connected vs disconnected'
},
subtitle: {
text: '3D donut in Highcharts'
},
plotOptions: {
pie: {
    innerSize: 100,
    depth: 45
   }
 },
 series: [{
name: 'Delivered amount',
data: [
    ['Connected', this.Connect_Total],
    ['DISCONNECTED', 3000],

    ]
 }]
}
}
```

I suggest you read up on how RxJS works ([here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) or [here](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754)). It's confusing to start with, but you powerful once you understand it.